# Removing a specific Class / Node from a Wordpress Site with a Vibez Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, class

Hello I have been fooling around with a dance studio Wordpress website theme I purchased for a couple days.  It probably would have been easier to start from scratch but I did not.  This theme has some animation with arrows that screen in from the left hand side.  Within the theme there is an option to turn off this animation but that does not seem to work.

My next thought was just to try and remove the class from the back-end but can't seem to figure out where that is located.  My question is basically How can I find this class to remove it?  Would you say that is the best course of action to remove it?

You can find both areas where the arrows are located at:

https://www.patonplacetestsite3.ca/about/

Class:

and

https://www.patonplacetestsite3.ca/contact-us/

Class:

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: sorry had the Class noted above but removed the formattng:  Class: div class="eltdf-row-arrows-holder eltdf-arrows-animate"

Answer (score 0):

```
.eltdf-has-arrows-animation.eltdf-arrows-ha-left .eltdf-row-arrows-holder {
```

display: none;
}
.eltdf-title.eltdf-title-has-arrows.eltdf-arrows-left .eltdf-title-arrows-holder {
display: none;
}